# Where will the variables created by reference space be stored? How will they be referenced to their reference space?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

I read that local variables will be stored in the stack memory and the reference variables will be stored in the heap memory.

Now I have a case where a local object is being created in a reference space. So where will that object be saved, and how will that object be referenced?

I'm trying to find out what variables are stored in stack memory and heap memory.

**Employee.cs**

```
        class Employee
        {
            int EmpId;
            public int GetEmpId()
            {
                 return this.EmpId ;
            }

            public void SetEmpId(int EmpId)
            {
                this.EmpId = EmpId;
            }

            public Job j = new Job();
        }
```

**Job.cs**

```
    class Job
    {
        int JobId;

        public int GetJobId()
        {
             return this.JobId ;
        }

        public void SetJobId(int JobId)
        {
            this.JobId = JobId;
        }

    }
```

**Program.cs**

```
    class Program
    {
        static int a =1;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Employee E1 = new Employee();
            Employee E2 = new Employee();

            E1.SetEmpId(2595);
            E1.j.SetJobId(25);

            Console.WriteLine(E1.GetEmpId());
            Console.WriteLine(E1.j.GetJobId());

        }

    }
```

I'm using Visual Studio Code.

Can anyone please help me in finding what goes into stack memory and what goes into heap memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Stack space*** is used for ***passing arguments to a method*** and 
for ***local variables*** defined within a method. Local variables of a reference type will be stored on the heap and pointer to that objects will be stored on stack. But, local variables of a value type will be stored on stack.

By the way, stack space is owned by threads. The default stack size is 1MB. Each thread gets a stack, while there's typically only one heap for the application.

And objects are stored on the heap alongside with all their fields and properties.

Now, let's go line by line.

```
static int a = 1;
```

Static fields will be stored in the heap alongside with `Type` object. Because, static fields actually related to `Type` object which will be created automatically by CLR on first access to the instance of that `Type` or directly to the `Type`. That `Type` object contains all type related information.

Then:

```
  Employee E1 = new Employee();
  Employee E2 = new Employee();
```

You have two `Employee` objects on the heap. And addresses of that objects in the stack(`E1` and `E2`). 
But, if `Employee` was a struct, then `E1` and `E2` will be stored on stack alongside with all information. If that struct has some field of a reference type, then data of that field will be stored on heap and address of that field will be stored on stack inside `Employee`.

Comment: can you tell me where will the 'j' object of E1 and E2 will be stored

Comment: @RadhaManohar Look, all objects of a refernce type will be stored on heap. As I told, both `Employee` objects will be stored in heap. Let's say in the addresses of `e1_address` and `e2_address`. And in stack, there will be two data `e1` and `e2`. `e1` will contain address of the first  `Employee`, which is `e1_address`. That object which is located in  `e1_address`, will hold all information about that `Employee`, `j` as well

Comment: @RadhaManohar No problem, don't for get to mark as answer if it helped. You can ask anything other about the topic as well. By the way, read CLR via C# book by Jeffrey Ritcher, especially from 101 - 110